# How does format(integer, 'string'+'string'+'string') work in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, format

I've been looking at some code for implementing the Dustsch-Jozsa algorithm using the Qiskit package. This context is not that relevant to the actual question. The problem I have is in understanding how the *format()* function works in the code fragment below(I'm kind of new to python):

```
n = 5 #or any non-zero positive integer
b = np.random.randint(1,2**n)
# Next, format 'b' as a binary string of length 'n', padded with zeros:
b_str = format(b, '0'+str(n)+'b')
```

I've tried a test run of this code in isolation and I looked at b, and b_str:

```
print(b)
print(b_str)
print('0'+str(n)+'b')
```

output:

```
9
01001
05b
```

All I could find about *format()* in documentation are uses of the form (which at first sight are not similar to the code above):

```
txt1 = "My name is {fname}, I'm {age}".format(fname = "John", age = 36)
txt2 = "My name is {0}, I'm {1}".format("John",36)
txt3 = "My name is {}, I'm {}".format("John",36)
```

So, can anyone explain how the first code actually works and what am I missing here?

Comment: Give [this section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) a read over. For the meaning of "b", scroll down to "The available integer presentation types are".

Comment: @Carcigenicate Oh, now I get it. So it makes b binary and fills with zeroes to the left until the length of the final string is n. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, you got it. That whole section is worth a few reads over because of how useful string formatting is.

Comment: Oh, also note that `format` is largely outdated. For recent versions of Python 3, "f-strings" are the replacement that allows for direct string interpolation. It uses roughly the same formatting syntax, but it's worth looking into.